# How to blacklist(filter) a list c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, listbox

I am trying to filter a existing list, currently my code will output me the following:

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
CHEVRON -- 90,02 € -- 200 PCS -- 18004 €
DEUTSCHE_BOERSE_NA_O.N. -- 139,00 € -- 100 PCS -- 13900 €
VONOVIA_SE -- 50,94 € -- 170 PCS -- 8659,8 €
SAP_SE -- 112,86 € -- 50 PCS -- 5643 €
```

I want to further filter the output by removing specific names by giving the first word into a richtextbox

**MY RICHTEXTBOX:**

```
CHEVRON SAP
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
DEUTSCHE BOERSE NA O.N. -- 139,00 € -- 100 PCS -- 13900 €
VONOVIA SE -- 50,94 € -- 170 PCS -- 8659,8 €
```

**MY CURRENT WORKING CODE:**

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] clist = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
                string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, clist);
                listBox3.Items.Clear();
                var germanCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");


                var map = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                foreach (string f in clist)
                {
                    var inputs = f.Split(new[] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Creates a list of strings

                    var unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[1].Split(' ')[0], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
                    var numUnits = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[2].Split(' ')[0]);

                    var key = inputs[0];
                    var pieces = inputs[2];
                    var price = inputs[1];
                    if (map.ContainsKey(key)) map[key] = numUnits * unitPrice;
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            map.Add(key + " --" + price + " -- " + pieces, numUnits * unitPrice);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
                var sortedMap = map.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);

                foreach (var item in sortedMap)
                {
               
                    listBox3.Items.Add(item.Key + " -- " + item.Value + " €");
                }
         

            } catch (Exception E)
            {


            }
        }
```

**WHAT I TRIED:**

```
listboxfilteritems1 = listBox3.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
                string[] listboxfilteritems2 = listboxfilteritems1
                        .Select(s => s.Replace("_", " "))
                        .ToArray()
                        ;
                listboxfilteritems3 = new List<string>(listboxfilteritems2.Where(l => !richTextBox3.Text.Split().Any(s => l.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)));
                listBox3.DataSource = listboxfilteritems3;
```

**THE PROBLEM**

```
Simply nothing happens and the programm crashes if I dont catch the general exception
```

Comment: And what kind of exception do you get? What is the exception's content?

Comment: Log your exceptions. Empty catch blocks are a big red flag. And unrelated: Make sure, `double` is precise enough for your requirements. Usually, it is discouraged to use floating point types for monetary values.

Comment: Assuming this is Winforms: What type is your timer, exactly? I am anticipating an Exception due to cross-thread UI-Component access.

Answer (score 0):

In my programs to filter a list i create a copy of it that is the one that i display, then when i activate the filters i just go though the list checking for conditions:

```
        List<Object> yourOriginalList = ...;
        foreach (var o in yourOriginalList)
        {
            if (condition)
                displayList.Add(o);
        }
        displayList.Sort();
        ....ItemsSource = displayList;
```

If you have the posibility to use LinQ it will work really nice:

```
public Object[] displayList (Object[] item)
{
    return item.Where(i => condition...).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use specific types instead of "var" to make the code a bit more readble, specifically for this bit of your code.

```
Dictionary<string, double> map = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                foreach (string f in clist)
                {
                    string[] inputs = f.Split(new[] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Creates a list of strings

                    double unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[1].Split(' ')[0], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
                    double numUnits = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[2].Split(' ')[0]);

                    string key = inputs[0];
                    string pieces = inputs[2];
                    string price = inputs[1];
                    if (map.ContainsKey(key)) map[key] = numUnits * unitPrice;
```

Because this may lead to some confusion, for example, "inputs" is not a list, but an array of strings.

Continuing, I've done some assumptions over the code that's missing that may or may not be true.

I guess this is the line of code where you are getting an exception:

```
listboxfilteritems3 = new List<string>(listboxfilteritems2.Where(l => !richTextBox3.Text.Split().Any(s => l.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)));
```

Assuming that the StringComparison contains the correct key, I don't see anything inherently wrong with it, but maybe if you try write and debug the code without the lamda expression you may be able to see some data inside the attributes that can be wrong. I tried writing a bit of the schema of how it could be, but beware I am not sure of some of the types here:

```
    listboxfilteritems3 = new List<string>();
    bool addText = true;
    foreach(string item1 in listboxfilteritems3){
        foreach(string textBox in richTextBox3.Text.Split('?')){
            if(!item1.Equals(textBox)){
                addText=false;
            }
        }
        if(addText){
            listboxfilteritems3.Add(item1);

        }
        addText=true;
    }
```

And you coul'd try either to debug it by hand or ad some try catch blocks that specify the error.

I haven't specified the correct character that should be used by the separator I left it as a '?', and I am assuming that you are managing the fact tahat, like in the example you provided, you may be entering substrings of a key instead of the exact key, or is beeing managed by the CultureInfo.

Anyway, I can't think of any better way to find the error, hope it helps.